# Shooting Script for Projectiles Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a prefab for a fireball and a transform on the staff of the player to spawn the fireball from. The script is supposed to create a clone when the left mouse button is fired, grab the rigidbody from it, then addforce to it to make the fireball move. However, the fireball only spawns and does not move. The game is 2D and the gameplay is similar to binding of isaac in terms of the camera view and what axis the player can move along.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerFire : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject fireball; 
    public int projectSpeed = 20;
    public Transform fireTrans;
    private bool shootEvent = false;
    private Vector2 mousePos;
    private GameObject Temporary_Projectile_Handler;
    private Rigidbody2D Temporary_Rigidbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            shootEvent = setAim();
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        if (shootEvent == true)
        {
            shoot();
        }
    }

    private bool setAim()
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Temporary_Projectile_Handler = Instantiate(fireball, fireTrans.position, fireTrans.rotation);
        Temporary_Rigidbody = Temporary_Projectile_Handler.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Temporary_Projectile_Handler.SetActive(true);

        return (true);
    }

    private void shoot()
    {
        Temporary_Rigidbody.AddForce((transform.forward * projectSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        shootEvent = false;

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your description, you should use 2D axes for movement and orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the movement script for the bullet on the bullet gameobject itself. And I recommend doing something like this for your shooting script:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    //Shooting code here
}
```